# Making equations follow the theorem counter

Tags: equations, numbering

I'm aware that several questions similar to this one have been posted, but I haven't found one that does quite exactly what I will ask below.

Here's what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{teo}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
\begin{teo} A theorem. \end{teo}
\begin{equation} 0=1 \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

I would like the (1) next to the equation to be 1.2. On the next section, a similar pattern would occur, only starting with 2.

Answer (score 2):

You can make `teo` follow the `equation` counter:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{teo}[equation]{Theorem}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
\begin{teo} A theorem. \end{teo}
\begin{equation} 0=1 \end{equation}
\begin{teo} A theorem. \end{teo}
\begin{equation} 0=1 \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]